# Does angular daterangepicker create its own scope?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datetimepicker

I have decided to use [angular-daterangepicker](https://github.com/fragaria/angular-daterangepicker) as a filter inside an ngTable. So what I do is simply create a filter that points to my template

```
filter[name] = 'partials/rangeFilter.tpl.html';
```

This template contains only the date range picker:

```
<input date-range-picker 
       class="form-control date-picker"
       type="text"
       name="DateRange" 
       ng-model="dateRange" 
       options="dateRangeOpts" 
       clearable="true"
       format="DD/MM/YYY"
       min="'2015-01-01'" max="'2025-01-01'"
       ng-change="rangeUpdate(dateRange)"
       required />
```

It is shown correctly, but if I change the dates nothing will happen in my main controller. Even though the element is initialized correctly with the value of `dateRange` it is as if after that `daterangepicker` is cloning it in its own scope and using that model instead.

I believe that because if I try to show this variable `{{dateRange}}` inside the template it is update correctly. If I try to show it in my main page then it constantly shows its initial value.

What I would like to know is if what I suspect is true, and if yes where and how exactly, in `daterangepicker`'s code, so I can try and make `ng-change` work properly.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal not sure I understand the question.

Comment: Yes it has . Checkout the documentation .

Comment: @katmanco I see nothing relevant on the project's readme except from the warning on making sure to use `$scope.DateRange.date` instead of `$scope.date`. But that does not have any effect.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/fragaria/angular-daterangepicker/blob/master/js/angular-daterangepicker.js there you will see that directive has its own scope . I found this blog http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/11/mastering-the-scope-of-a-directive-in-angularjs/ that explains **scopes in more detail** and very clear  .

Comment: The blog suggested is very clear and helpful indeed. I will read it in more detail and try to find a way to make daterangepicker actually do something in a datechange.

Comment: Even though in the official demo, the watcher works correctly! So this could be a weirder problem than what I originally thought.